# Help with regression

Tags: spss

I have a dichotomous variable, "know" and "not know". This refers to a participant knowing the meaning of a word or not.

Then I have another variable as "fixation duration" which is continuous.

I want to know if participants have higher fixation durations (look more) on the words whose meaning they do not know. In other words, I hypothesize that knowing a meaning of a word predicts fixation duration.

So my outcome is continuous and the predictor is dichotomous. Which statistical test should I use: linear regression, logistic regression or what?

Comment: Could you explain why you are considering regression solutions when the only predictor is dichotomous? In many cases people would just look at this as two groups of results, one for "know" and the other for "not know." This leads me to suspect that you might have multiple observations of each participant and that participant identifier should be considered a covariate. This suggests that editing this question to disclose more information about the nature and amount of these data will help you get answers that are actually useful and appropriate.

Comment: Hi Wuber, as far as I understand you are suggesting a group comparison test like t test by grouping them into two as "know" and "not know." But what I want to scrutinize is a causal relationship between two variables. Is not regression better in explaining such situations?

Comment: If in fact you are not using participant identifier as a covariate, regression methods cannot be any better than two-group comparison methods: the only role played by your dichotomous predictor within regression is to segregate the data into two groups internally anyway. In fact, regression methods can actually be *worse* because they tend to assume the sizes of variation within each group are approximately the same.  Regression methods would be indicated only when you have covariate information to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a linear regression with one outcome (`Fixation`) and three predictors: `Word`, `IsKnown`, and `Participant`. In other words, you will attempt to explain the fixation length as the sum of those three factors, and you'll see whether the `IsKnown` effect is statistically significant. As others have pointed out, because `Fixation` is continuous, you'll want a linear regression. Logistic regression is appropriate for dichotomous outcomes.

To run through the regression explicitly, here's a fake data set I just made up:

[image]

And here's how you'd build that model in Wizard:

[image]

And what the results should look like:

[image]

Here you can see that the p-value for `[IsKnown = Yes]` is quite small, and would conclude that there is a statistically significant negative effect. (According to the model, knowing the word on average results in a fixation duration of 0.791 seconds less than not knowing the word. Also participant D is a very fast reader compared to the others!)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer Emiller, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you found it useful, Emrah Dolgunsöz. If it fully answers your question, don't forget to "Accept" the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The place to start, anyway, is linear regression.  The dependent variable (outcome variable) is the key thing.

Comment: Thanks Peter for such a quick answer. I have 15 words and 15 fixation durations so that means I have to do 15 linear regression?

Comment: No. Only one regression.

Comment: Oh i see but how? By restructuring the data? each word (word1, word2...) is a dichotomous variable and each corresponding fixation duration is another variable (wordfx1, wordfx2...) in my data set.

Comment: You should have 3 variables: Word, know, and fixation

Comment: Yes Peter I did it by restructuring the data like I did before for mixed model repeated measures but this time N in regression results is 15 times more than the real sample size as I have 15 different words.

Comment: No, it isn't. N = 15. There is one regression.